# How to create GitHub environment variables with object-like syntax to test a bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm currently coding a shell script for my GitHub Workflow and I want to test it locally.

However, it depends on an env variable provided by GitHub that consists of multiple nested segments, like a Javascript object for example.

**my-bash-file.sh**

```
PAYLOAD=${github.event.client_payload}
echo "$PAYLOAD"
```

**How would I declare and inject such a kind of env variable locally when calling my script?**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here: are you asking, "How do I set an environment variable?", or are you asking something else? Note that the example you've given just sets the `PAYLOAD` environment variable to a string value, which is exactly what you can do in the shell e.g. by setting `PAYLOAD="some value"; export PAYLOAD` (or variations thereof).

Comment: @larsks sry, I've changed the original post to make it a bit clearer. The problem is, I need to inject env `github.event.client_payload` into the bash script, but I can't declare it. even using `env` does not have the wished effect and I get `bad substitution`

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you're trying to do? In your local environment there won't be any variabled named `github.event.client_payload` (that's not event a valid variable name); you would have to provide an appropriate value yourself. In the context of a GitHub action, that's not an environment variable -- it's a template value that is substituted with an actual value *before* your script actually runs.

Comment: There is no "object-like syntax" environment variables. There are no "nested segments" in environment variables. A variable has a name and a value. These are no objects. `How would I declare` It's not possible without writing a bash plugin or modifying souce code.

Answer (score 1):

While you can define environment variables containing dots you won't be able to reference them from `bash` as *identifiers* can consist only of alphanumeric characters and underscores.

However, you can access them using other languages, like python. Call it `my-python` for example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os

payload=os.environ['github.event.client_payload']
print(f'payload={payload}')
```

invoking it as

```
env github.event.client_payload=hello ./my-python
```

produces

```
payload=hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. You're running a shell script as part of a GitHub action that looks something like this:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install pre-commit
        run: |
          PAYLOAD=${github.event.client_payload}
          echo "$PAYLOAD"
```

The best solution is to not reference github template variables directly in your shell script. Write it like this instead:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install pre-commit
        env:
          PAYLOAD: "${github.event.client_payload}"
        run: |
          echo "$PAYLOAD"
```

This keeps the github template variable out of your script and instead uses it to set the `PAYLOAD` environment variable before the script runs. If you want to run the same script locally, you would just need to set the same `PAYLOAD` environment variable.

---

The examples here show a script embedded in the GitHub workflow; that's because there's no way to use a template variable embedded in a script *file* as you've shown in your question. If your workflow tried to run a script `my-bash-file.sh` that contained:

```
#!/bin/sh
PAYLOAD=${github.event.client_payload}
echo "$PAYLOAD"
```

It would fail with:

```
my-bash-file.sh: line 2: ${github.event.client_payload}: bad substitution
```